# JavaScript class - can I make a "final" property?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a JavaScript class and I want to create a property that cannot be reassigned. In JavaScript, a `const` would normally work, but I don't know how to do this at the class level. In Java, I would use a "final" property.

Currently, I am using the following code:

```js
class MyClass {

  // I want this to never change after the first compute
  "final" someProperty = computeSomeValue();  // computeSomeValue is imported

  // one option is to use "get"
  get someProperty() {
    // issue is that the function is run each time this property is accessed and I'd need more logic to cache it.
    return computeSomeValue();
  }

}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this in JavaScript without using "get"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the property non-writable and non-configurable using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
class MyClass {
  someProperty = computeSomeValue();

  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "someProperty", {
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
    });
  }
}
```

or

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "someProperty", {
      value: computeSomeValue(),
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
    });
  }
}
```

That way, attempts to write to the property will cause an exception, just like with your setter-less getter property.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) (which you might like if you come from a Java background where things are more strongly typed), you could declare it to be `readonly`.

```ts
class MyClass {
  readonly someProperty = computeSomeValue();
}
```

However, when compiled to JavaScript this will still allow access since in the end it still outputs a JS class.

If your goal is only to let developers know this value shouldn't be changed (just like `const` does), then this will work. If your goal is to prevent users from changing the code, there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Would this error out at compile time if someone tried to modify it?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon yes it throws `Cannot assign to 'someProperty' because it is a read-only property.` https://tsplay.dev/Nr9dzw

Comment: Yep!  That's why TypeScript is so great!  It provides a better development experience, but still outputs JavaScript.  Follow that line @Konrad posted and check the right side for `.JS` to see the output.  This will error for developers at compile time, but users consuming the generated JS could still modify it (but this is unavoidable)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) <s>but it doesn't throw an error when you try to modify the property</s>

Edit: it throws an error in strict mode

```js
'use strict'
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'final', {
      configurable: false,
      writable: false,
      value: 123
    })
  }
}

const x = new MyClass()

console.log(x.final)

x.final = 4

console.log(x.final)
```

Comment: "*it doesn't throw an error*" - only if you forget to use strict mode